# is it possible to run old java web app on new tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, java-8

I have an old java web app based on servlet spec 2.3. I use struts 1, jsf 1.1, etc. Can I run this app on tomcat 8? I read there is a severe compatibility issue, but can't it be resolved?

Comment: We might be able to help you with more *concrete* questions, where you show us code and error messages or API changes, but not give a blank statement about expected problems from just a two-line question naming random software versions followed by "etc."

Comment: The only way to know for sure whether it will work is to actually try it. Once you have done that, try to resolve the errors you might have. Also, if you have concerns about a specific compatibility issue, please specify it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html) for Tomcat 8:

> Any installed Java 7 or later JRE (32-bit or 64-bit) may be used.

When you run your web application in Tomcat, you are running on the same JVM which powers Tomcat.

In any case, your old webapp uses Java 2, which, among other problems, likely has several known security holes.  You might be able to upgrade the code without too much pain in a good IDE (such as IntelliJ).

Comment: thanks, but the issue is jsf and other frameworks will not work in servlet 2.3

Comment: @avalon You were asking whether your old webapp will work in a newer Tomcat. Tomcat 8 supports Servlet 3.1, so any technology your old app was using is supported at least in principle.

Comment: @Tim an application does not normally need to be recompiled to run on a newer version of Java.

Comment: Noted.  But why does Tomcat require a certain recent Java version?  It too is a Java program.

Comment: Most likely they made changes to their own code base that require Java 7 or later, or they only compile and test it on Java 7 and they don't want to support older versions. The OP's app also requires some Java _X_ _or later_, so Java 7 should work for his app too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  An older application could require an older version of  JVM (1.4 for example) but it should be possible to execute it with a recent JVM.